# Is it possible to change the thumbnail when we make an apprequest?

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to change the thumbnail when we make an app request using the PHP-SDK? it is the app's thumbnail i see when i make an app generated request.

Answer (score 0):

just as you cannot change the name of your application when sending any app request - you can not change the thumbnail.  Many times users will recognize your application by the thumbnail - just as a user will recognized another by his profile picture.